# What is the main aim and object of the kings pawn opening?

Tags: opening

I think that every opening has a particular aim and object.
Can someone tell me the the aim and object of the kings pawn opening?

Comment: "to win the game" ?

Comment: But how?not every openings of kings pawn win the game.

Comment: if you don't win, you're just playing it wrong =)

Comment: Then how to play it right?how can i learn it that i can play it right?

Comment: I think this is not too broad, the question "what is the goal of 1.e4" can be answered. It's not extremely interesting as much depends on what happens next, but it's not too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the goal of the opening is to develop the pieces (knights and bishops in particular) to active squares and to gain space for operation of the pieces (usually achieved by occupying the center with pawns).

If we are talking about the kings pawn opening, i.e. any opening that starts with 1. e4, there is little to say besides:

- white aims to occupy the center with a pawn on e4
- white makes space for the development of the light squared bishop on f1 (and potentially the queen)

Note that the game after 1.e4 could develop in all kinds of ways of very different character. Many of these openings have their own name (Sicilian, Ruy-Lopez, French, Caro Kann...), their own aims and objectives. Really I'd struggle to call a single move like 1. e4 an "opening".

Also often you will find that proper openings like those mentioned above will be listed by their name while the name King's Pawn Opening is reserved for all the rest, i.e. for games that don't follow any of the established openings.